# Describe the level curves of $f(x,y) = \frac{y}{x^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I guess I would show that $z = \frac{y}{x^2}$. I know the Domain is x does not equal 0 and range is all real  numbers. I'm assuming I would use that fact somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

When we say describe the level curve, we are looking at $f(x,y)$ as a surface in 3D, and intersecting it with a plane parallel to the $x$-$y$ plane.

When this plane intersects the surface, if forms a curve.  We are interested in the shape of this curve.

So say this plane is at height $z=c$. Then setting $c = \frac{y}{x^2}$ yields $y=cx^2$. This equation describes a family of parabolas.  Such a parabola will have $(0,0,c)$ as vertex.

Comment: So to describe all level curves, I would instead of having a constant c, I could plus in z representing every value of z?

Comment: @dirtysocks45 I wouldn't use $z$. You should be thinking of $c$ as a $z$-value. Here $c$ can be any value on the $z$ axis; so it is a parameter.

Comment: I would say that $f(x, y)$ is a real number; the *graph* of $f$, or of $z = f(x, y)$, is a surface in 3D.